# Synchronised Data Extensions

Tags: marketing-cloud, sales-cloud

I am currently synchronising Sales Cloud objects to Marketing Cloud. In the Configuration I have three options to do this:

- Sync All records
- Sync only records with email address
- or Sync records as at a certain date

However, none of these suit our needs. We need to cut our number of synced records down by nearly 100,000. Ideally we would like to sychronise data using our own filters. Is there a way to do this?

I have created a Case, but the only solution they have been able to provide is to create a Data Filter within Marketing Cloud. However, I'm pretty sure this doesn't reduce the number of records synced to Marketing Cloud. I believe it only creates a filtered DE.

Thanks,
Jackie

Answer (score 2):

Currently these are your only three options available; however, after the release that was scheduled for today (October 27th, 2017) there will exist the added functionality of being able to filter records at the synchronization level based on any selected boolean fields.

> Synchronized Data Sources can use a boolean field value to define the object rows that are synchronized to Marketing Cloud. Only rows that meet the filter requirement synchronize to Marketing Cloud. When an update to the boolean field longer meets the filter requirement, we remove the row from the synchronized data extension.

[Source](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/release_notes/october_2017_release/integrations/)

As far as I can tell this hasn't been released yet, but if you wait a little while longer it should be made available.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can create a boolean field in Salesforce objects to filter the records you want to sync to Marketing Cloud.

From [Oct 2017 release](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/release_notes/october_2017_release/integrations/), you can now use Synchronized Data Source Boolean Field Filter

> Synchronized Data Sources can use a boolean field value to define the object rows that are synchronized to Marketing Cloud. Only rows that meet the filter requirement synchronize to Marketing Cloud. When an update to the boolean field longer meets the filter requirement, we remove the row from the synchronized data extension.

But be aware of this restriction

> You cannot use formula fields as a filter.